# error when I do 'pik add' ruby 192 installed by heroku toolbelt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, pik

I installed pik and I put ruby 187 and 193. then I installed Heroku toolbel to load then my application on it, which automatically installs ruby 192 in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ruby​​-1.9.3\bin
```

but I can not add it to pik ... I try to do this and similar :

```
pik add C:\Program Files (x86)\ruby​​-1.9.3\bin
```

but the console gives me error:

```
could not find a ruby version at C:\Program
```

probably wrong with the command spaces, I can not find a solution!
With 'where ruby' the console returns:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ruby​​-1.9.3\bin\ruby.exe
C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe
C:\Ruby187\bin\ruby.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages suggests, that pik tries to add "C:\Program", which means it doesn't like spaces in the path. You probably need to give the path in quotes, like this:

```
pik add "C:\Program Files (x86)\ruby​​-1.9.3\bin"
```